# Break word into lines with word-break doesn't work in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I have some text with this css:

`word-break: break-word;`

What it is supposed to do is to break the text into lines when I reduce the dimensions of the window. It is responsive and works fine in Chrome but has no effect in Internet Explorer 11. I've searched a lot about this but nothing solved my problem.

If it helps, this is the css class for the container of the text:

```
.my-class {
    width: 170px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: flex-end;
    text-align: end;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post a working example?

Comment: break-word is completly compatible with IE - Flex on the other hand, is not..

Comment: IE 11 requires a unit to be added to the third argument, the flex-basis property

Comment: In IE10 and IE11, containers with display: flex and flex-direction: column will not properly calculate their flexed childrens' sizes if the container has min-height but no explicit height property.

Comment: IE 11 does not vertically align items correctly when min-height is used

Comment: @Stender can you be more specific? :)

Comment: Internet explorer 10 and 11 only have partial support for display: flex;

Comment: which could be your problem

Comment: is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

For flexbox to work in IE, you can change your code to:

```
.my-class {
    width: 170px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: flex-end;
    text-align: end;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -moz-justify-content: space-around;
    -ms-justify-content: space-around;
    -o-justify-content: space-around;
    -ms-flex-pack: space-around;
    box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```

Comment: Looking forward to hear if this answer works flawlessly, because i've had similar problems before.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't change anything